# Jsoup Read Time Out depending on UserAgent String

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler, user-agent

I am trying to work on few urls with Jsoup. One such example is :

http://www.aceshowbiz.com/movie/

When I do :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

It throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

But when I set a useragent string, it works fine

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Chrome").get();
```

Though it doesn't work on other UserAgent Strings :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").get();
//again a Read Time Out
```

My query here is : such kind of cases happen a lot with me when a website allows a certain useragent string and some sites download only when using no useragent string at all. I am not sure what causes such behavior. What is work around of this. And as I said, on some sites, I can download only when using no useragent string at all. Is it some kind of restriction from on the server end ? Or if a website doesn't downloads with useragent string of my crawler, I should respect it and should not try more cases or is it some kind of error. Certainly not sure why sites doesn't allows certain useragent strings/and few get downloaded when using no useragent string at all.

I tested few useragent strings on http://www.bloombergview.com/topics/entertainment as well and found it gets downloaded only on few. How can we decide on which it works ?

If it is an issue with Jsoup, should I try downloading page by hand using http and feeding it Jsoup.parse(html) ? Not sure will get same kind of problem there as well.

Edit :I hope I am able to convey the problem :-> how to chose a right useragent string for my crawler that is able to download all sites. I will definitely add my crawler name to the useragent string (if this info matters), but I am getting problems now with general strings available like above. Not sure what is happening in above cases.

Comment: I tried with the user agent you posted and it works.

Comment: thanks for comment. aceshowbiz doesnt seem to work with anything other than "chrome" and bloomberg one works with the long useragent string posted above. need to understand what's happening and why sites work with few useragent strings and few doesn't work. and a work around.

Comment: You saild `I tested few useragent strings on http://www.bloombergview.com/topics/entertainment as well and found it gets download **only** when using **no useragent** string.`

Comment: If that's not the case please update your question.

Comment: About this one `I tested few useragent strings on http://www.bloombergview.com/topics/entertainment as well and found it gets downloaded only on few. How can we decide on which it works ?` please post one of the user agents that has a problem.

Comment: updated question, and please see example of aceshowbiz.com above. I have posted one string which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About [aceshowbiz](http://www.aceshowbiz.com/movie/) , the problem is not with userAgent, but with the timeout option.
Try this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.aceshowbiz.com/movie/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                  //.userAgent("Chrome")
                    .timeout(0)  
                    .get();
```

I would like to see an example of a userAgent working and another one not working.
Do you have one?

`timeout(0)`  This removes the timeout limit. You could just add some big number, that's still acceptable in terms of performance

Comment: thanks. its working when using referrer. Not sure if it is moral/legal/valid to use referrer in a crawler, but going to use it anyways. the problem was from aceshowbiz and when I tweak useragent string for it, other sites didn't worked. I am analyzing all my database once again to see any such error exists.

Comment: I've checked it a little more. The problem is not with referrer header, it's with the default timeout option that jsoup has. Please see my update, it should work without referrer. For some reason, when using referrer it works somewhat faster, so you don't surpass that timeout limit. Check the updated code.

Comment: It works even without the userAgent header. It's just a lot slower.

Comment: It's a bit weird, but I solved the issue also when added `.userAgent("Opera")` as option and .timeout(0) and other values didn't help me.